# how to store login information using onsen ui?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I want to use onsen ui and angularjs to develop a hybird application, but now I meet a problem, this application cannot store user's login information, so user must login everytime after they close the application.

I use $cookies, service, and $rootScope to store user's login information, but all of them can not work at android platform.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem？

Comment: Minor suggestion, but you should hash the password for security reasons. Then whenever they log back in, rehash their password input and compare it to the saved hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On HTML5 mobile framework like Onsenui, I suggest to use localStorage.

You can take a look at these two AngularJs modules:

- [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)
- [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

They have very well written instructions and demo codes as references.

Answer (score 3):

use this plugin https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage or something similar to create a sqlite database. Create a table with the information you want to keep (username and password). You can create a hash of the password and store it for better security (md5 or sha1).

You can also keep the timestamp of the login and keep the user logged in for a specific interval of time, so when he opens the app, check if you are inside this interval (e.g. day, week, etc.) from the last login and if yes, log him in automatically else show the login screen again.

Comment: It sounds good, I will to learn how to use it.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (window.localStorage.getItem("rememberMe") == "true") {
        $scope.userEmail = window.localStorage.getItem("userName");
        $scope.userPassword = window.localStorage.getItem("password");
        document.getElementById("rememberMe").checked = true;
 }
 else {
       document.getElementById("rememberMe").checked = false;
 }
 if (document.getElementById("rememberMe").checked == true) {
       window.localStorage.setItem("rememberMe", "true");
       window.localStorage.setItem("userName", $scope.userEmail);
       window.localStorage.setItem("password", $scope.userPassword);
 }
 else if (document.getElementById("rememberMe").checked == false) {
     window.localStorage.setItem("rememberMe", "false");
     window.localStorage.setItem("userName", "");
     window.localStorage.setItem("password", "");
 }
```

Hi! have a look at the above code. It stores in local storage